# Can I use InkManager.RecognizeAsync to recognize mathemathical formulas?

Tags: c#, uwp, inkcanvas

Nebo and OneNote can both recognize mathemathical formulas and symbols like greek letters, integrals and exponents. Is there a way to achieve the same? Or would I have to train my own recognizer?

Comment: Currently, InkManager  has not provide api to recognize mathematical formulas, you may train your own recognizer.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I assume there is no way to use or extract the one from OneNote?

Comment: Currently, OneNote has not provide such feature that could be extracted, so you may train your own recognizer, And If you do want this feature, Please post on the [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/).